# XPath: counting elements excluding another elements from count

Tags: xpath

I need to count all the elements that includes text 'Automation' but excluding the `span[@class = "hot"]` elements from the count.

The site with a html code is : https://www.epam.com/careers/job-listings?sort=best_match&query=&department=Software+Test+Engineering&city=all&country=all

I can count every search result by:

```
count(//li[contains(@class, 'search-result-item')])
```

and it works as needed but how should I include only the elements with

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Automation')]
```

and exclude the search result elements that has

```
span[@class = "hot"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selects `li` that does not have a span with `class="hot"` and from there select your `a` link.

It should be something like:

```
//li[not(.//span[@class="hot"])]//a[contains(text(), 'Automation')]
```

You could also add other restraints for `li` to have a certain class and/or from certain section.